# setting maxlength using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to set the maxlength on input fields dynamically using JavaScript. Apparently that is a problem in IE, and I found part of the solution.

```
$("input#title").get(0).setAttribute("max_length", 25);
$("input#title").get(0).setAttribute(
                        "onkeypress", 
                        "return limitMe(event, this)");

function limitMe(evt, txt) {
    if (evt.which && evt.which == 8) return true;
    else return (txt.value.length < txt.getAttribute("max_length");
}
```

It works in Firefox, but not in IE for some reason. However, it works on input fields set like this:

```
<input type="text" max_length="25" onkeypress="return limitMe(event, this);"/>
```

But since the input fields are created dynamically, I can't do this... Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using jQuery then why not make full use of its abstractions?

E.g.

Instead of:

```
$("input#title").get(0).setAttribute("max_length", 25);
$("input#title").get(0).setAttribute(
                        "onkeypress", 
                        "return limitMe(event, this)");
function limitMe(evt, txt) {
    if (evt.which && evt.which == 8) return true;
    else return (txt.value.length < txt.getAttribute("max_length");
}
```

Do this:

```
$('input#title').attr('maxLength','25').keypress(limitMe);

function limitMe(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 8) { return true; }
    return this.value.length < $(this).attr("maxLength");
}
```

---

Edit: The reason it's not working in IE is probably because of how you attached the 'onKeyPress' handler, via setAttribute. - This isn't the proper way to register event handlers.

Comment: and I found that jQuery's attr() actually manage to set maxlength the proper way, so I don't have to use my own function. Excellent! Thanks, man (:

Answer (score 5):

The attribute you're looking for is `maxlength`, not `max_length`. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4).

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the fact that you can't set "maxlength" dynamically in IE.

Answer (score 3):

IE is case sensitive on setAttribute() and only "maxLength" works...

```
var el=document.createElement('input'); el.setAttribute('maxLength',25);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget though that if you are setting the maxlength via JavaScript, someone else could just as easily change the maxlength to whatever they like. You will still need to validate the submitted data on the server.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here relies on keypress/paste events. Here is my solution using the `input` event:

```
$('input').on('input', onInput);

var inputValue = '';

function onInput(e) {
    if(e.currentTarget.value.length > 30) {
        e.currentTarget.value = titleValue;
        return;
    }

    inputValue = e.currentTarget.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I had some trouble with the answer from @James I wrote sth that worked even when     copy-pasting stuff, and especially when working with IE8 and down. My implementation uses jQuery and its live-events.

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('body').on('keydown.maxlength_fix', 'textarea[maxlength]', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var val = $this.val();
            var maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength');
            if (val.length > maxlength) {
                $this.val(val.substr(0, maxlength));
            }
        }, 4);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My code also print out the written/max characters, ignore that part.

```
$("[maxlength]").bind("keyup focusin", function(){
    var maxkey = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(this).parent().find(".counter").text(length+"/"+maxkey);
    if (length > maxkey) $(this).val(value.substring(0, maxkey));
}).bind("focusout", function(){$(this).parent().find(".counter").text("")});
```