# How to show an error message if user tries to enter more characters than maxlength on input field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, maxlength

How can I return an error message to users when they try to go past the max length on input field?

This is the code that I'm using in haml.

```
= f.input :title, placeholder: 'Enter Title', :input_html => { :class => "form-control", autocomplete: :off, :maxlength => 255 }
```

I've used maxlength here and it is working fine but I want to show an error just below the input field that "**You have reached maximum character length**".

Is there any way possible to accomplish this task?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need `JAVASCRIPT` for that.

Comment: Any suggestions? How can I achieve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633876/setting-maxlength-using-javascript check this url how to set maxlength using js for input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `input` triggering or `keyup` [JQUERY](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //make sure name attribute is the same
   $("input[name='title']").on('keyup', function() {
      if($(this).val().length > 255) {
        $(this).css({"color": "red"})
      }else{
        $(this).removeAttr( "style" )
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's your base code that can help you

in your application.js

```
$('#text-field-id').on('keyup', function() {
  if($(this).val().length > 1) {
    alert('this is max length ');
  }
});
```

Comment: Your code works, but it shows the message as an alert. I want to display the error message below the input field. Is it possible to achieve this?